# matrix computation problem, Theoretical derivation and code results do not match

Tags: matrix, eigen3

I want to solve the question below:
A point Pw is in the world coordinate system. A C0 coordinate system and the Pw in the Co coordinate is Pc0. Now, I transform the C0 coordinate system to C1 coordinate system, ask: How I transform the Pw subject to Pc0 = Pc1. 
The [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ozzipseri2b0sj3/computation.png?dl=0) shows how I calculate the transform T.

And the code to confirm the result is below, unfortunately, the Pc0 != Pc1. I don't know what's wrong with the computation. Can you provide some advice? Thanks a lot.

```
int main() {
    //Pw
    Eigen::Vector3d Pw ( 1,0,0 );

    //Tc0w
    Eigen::AngleAxisd rotation_vector_c0w ( M_PI/2, Eigen::Vector3d ( 1,0,0 ) );
    Eigen::Matrix3d Rc0w = rotation_vector_c0w.toRotationMatrix();
    Eigen::Vector3d tc0w (1,2,3);
    Eigen::Isometry3d Tc0w=Eigen::Isometry3d::Identity();               
    Tc0w.rotate ( rotation_vector_c0w );                                     
    Tc0w.pretranslate ( tc0w );
    std::cout << "Transform matrix Tc0w= \n" << Tc0w.matrix() <<std::endl;

    //Pc0
    Eigen::Vector3d Pc0 = Tc0w*Pw;
    std::cout<<"Pc0:"<<std::endl<<Pc0<<std::endl;

    //Tc1c0
    Eigen::AngleAxisd rotation_vector_c1c0 ( M_PI/4, Eigen::Vector3d ( 1,1,0 ) );
    Eigen::Vector3d tc1c0 (1,2,3);
    Eigen::Isometry3d Tc1c0=Eigen::Isometry3d::Identity();                
    Tc1c0.rotate ( rotation_vector_c1c0 );                                     
    Tc1c0.pretranslate ( tc1c0 );
    std::cout << "Transform matrix Tc1c0= \n" << Tc1c0.matrix() <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "Transform matrix Tc0c1= \n" << Tc1c0.inverse().matrix() <<std::endl;

    //compute T
    Eigen::Isometry3d T = Tc0w.inverse()* Tc1c0.inverse()*Tc0w;
    std::cout << "Transform matrix T= \n" << T.matrix() <<std::endl;

    //confirm Pc1
    Eigen::Vector3d Pc1 = Tc1c0*Tc0w*T*Pw;
    std::cout<<"Pc1 = "<<std::endl<<Pc1<<std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AngleAxis` requires a normalized rotation axis. Try this:

```
Eigen::AngleAxisd rotation_vector_c1c0 ( M_PI/4, Eigen::Vector3d ( 1,1,0 ).normalized() );
```

Corresponding link to documentation:
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1AngleAxis.html#ab58bae23f0af86d66d8aa1dc5c1dbe39

Comment: Yes! you are right. I'm careless, thank you very much.